# How to find more information about a given MySQL process?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a very slow query that is built by the ORM and I'm curios how could I find out the exact query being executed.

I cannot monitor it from the `mysql-slow.log` because it never finishes the execution (as in I don't have eternity to wait for it, more than an hour in an still waiting).

Also I cannot get the query from the ORM, just after execution. And the only way I think of getting it is from the process list.

```
show processlist \G
```

But my problem is that most of the query is trimmed of, even before the `from` keyword.

This question has been asked before but with no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741356/find-queries-from-process-id-mysql-5-1-x

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried enabling general logs and tried to catch the query?

Comment: Yes, note my mention about `mysql-slow.log`. The queries aren't written to the log file until they complete, which didn't happen in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your query is formatted in multiple lines, some MySQL clients will only display the first line. To see full output run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` query in MySQL console.